# How to find all the colors in a Texture2D, and saving them to an array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Sorry about the title, I wasn't entirely sure how to phrase it, but basically I am trying to increase an index based on how many colors there are in a given Texture2D. To do this I have written

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProvinceMapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Texture2D provinceMap;

    Color previousColor;
    Color[] provinceColors = { new Color(0, 0, 0) };

    int provinceIndex;

    private void Start()
    {
        provinceColors = new Color[100];

        GenerateProvinces();
    }

    public void GenerateProvinces()
    {
        // Check all pixels for different colors, and save each color
        // Potential Bug, saying 54 when there is at least 59 colors...
        for (int x = 0; x < provinceMap.width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < provinceMap.height; y++)
            {
                // If the current pixel isn't the previous pixel, and the pixels aren't the same, increase the index
                if (provinceMap.GetPixel(x, y) != previousColor && !provinceColors.Contains(provinceMap.GetPixel(x, y)))
                {
                    // Save the color so that its not picked again
                    provinceColors[provinceIndex] = provinceMap.GetPixel(x, y);

                    provinceIndex++;
                    previousColor = provinceMap.GetPixel(x, y);

                    Debug.Log("Different Colors/Province Index: " + provinceIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this...somewhat works. It will count up to 54 which originally I thought was the answer, but in this case its actually 59. I'm not sure why its not.

In the if I try to see if the pixel is different, but not the same as other pixels, and if that is true, then save the new color to the `provinceColor` array, increase the index and  set the previous color equal to the color that was just picked, and log the index. Again this prints 54, when the answer is 49. As for the Texture2D I am using, [image: the Texture2D]
[image: Texture2D settings]

Comment: I'm not a Unity dev... Could the incorrect count be due to `mipLevel`? Anyway, see `GetPixels` [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html)... "A single call to this function is usually faster than multiple calls to GetPixel," You're calling `GetPixel` up to 4 times for the *same* pixel. Instead, get the `Color[]` from `GetPixels`, then filter it for distinct values.

Comment: I just checked in Photoshop and it's finding 54 unique colours in the image plus transparent. I think the code is accurate and you were right the first time that the answer is 54(?)

Comment: Hm. It might be compression then Sven Viking, because you have the 50 US states, + water, and the islands are sometimes different colors. However I will double check, but thanks

As for rfModulator, I would do `GetPixels`, but I am still in the beginner state of C# as far as I am aware, and wasn't exactly sure how to do what I needed with `GetPixels`. I if can think up a way to adjust the code I will though, thanks. Also I don't think the `mipLevel` is causing it since Sven checked the mage straight out of GIMP and not Unity and got 54. I will try it though

Either way thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sven Viking solved this, and its not because of any error with the code, rather me just being dumb and apparently not knowing math. Anyway, thanks for the three of yall for trying to help me!

Edit: Ill set this to the answer when i can if I rememeber

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using that whole logic about storing colors and what not, simply switch the type of the "provinceColors" to a HashSet and add all the pixels to the hashset. You can do so by getting all pixels at once and passing it to the constructor of the hashset.

A HashSet will compare any new element you add to the existing ones and if it already exists it won't be added again so every element is unique.

Code:

```
public class ProvinceMapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D provinceMap;
    private HashSet<Color> _provinceColors;

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateProvinces();
    }

    private void GenerateProvinces()
    {
        Color[] pixels = provinceMap.GetPixels();
        _provinceColors = new HashSet<Color>(pixels);
        Debug.Log($"Color count: {_provinceColors.Count}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently all I need is the amount of colors for testing purposes, but eventually I will need to "assign" these colors to different things (provinces), among other things, so while the count of it is what I showed, and asked for, it was more of trying to figure out why it was spiting out 54 colors, in which case it was probably my fault with GIMP than the actual code. I will keep this in mijnd in case I need to do something similar though, thanks!